# Placing marks outside coordinate system with pgfplots

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots, plot

I have a table of data (time vs. time) in a separate file and want to plot it with pgfplots. It works fine, but I have some special values denoting timeout in that table and I want to put them outside the coordinate grid to show that. I can choose these special values in any way I want, but I have not found a way to encode this. How does one do that without adding the timeouts manually?

The image below (generated "manually", without pgfplots) shows roughly how I want it to look:

[image]

Comment: How do you denote time out?

Comment: Currently, I have a negative number in my table, but I can generate these entries arbitrarily, in whatever way is convenient to achieve this with pgfplots